# Foundation Zurb 3 Orbit Counter Numbers?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have an Orbit slider in a Foundation 3 site, and I need to be able to show slide numbers, as in "slide 3 of 8".

I see no options for that in the docs, but looking at the _settings.scss file I see these items:

```
$orbitSlideNumBgColor: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
$orbitSlideNumFontColor: #fff;
$orbitSlideNumPadding: 5px;
```

But there's no indication how to use them. Uncommenting them doesn't do anything.  How to integrate with a given slider, or do I need to do my oen coding to create numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the jquery.foundation.orbit.js file ... Here all options are listed. You want to:

```
$("#slider").orbit({ slideNumber: true });
```

Agreed that should have been documented :)